# Creating a Weibull probability density

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to include a probability density of a Weibull distribution as a part of my document as an equation. Essentially the same basic density on the wikipedia page of Weibull distributions   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution). This is my attempt to code the equation I want.

```
\begin{equation}

f_X(x; \lambda, k) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
    \frac{k}{\lambda}(\frac{x}{k})^{k-1} e^{-(x/\lambda)^k} & \ ; \ x \geq 0 \\
    0 & \ ; \ x < 0 \end{array} \right. \


\end{equation}
```

This generates the correct form of equation, but I get a missing $ inserted error from this code. I read up on the error and think that some of the symbols I'm using inside the mathmode of `\equation` may not be appropriate although I'm not sure how to find out.

Comment: Just remove the empty lines after `\begin{equation}` and before `\end{equation}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Thank you! That has indeed solved it, I didn't know the \equation{} environment was so sensitive to empty lines.

Comment: Empty lines in (La)TeX denote the end of a paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to getting rid of the blank lines inside the `equation` environment to take care of the immediate problem, you may want to enhance the overall look of the equation, mainly by replacing the generic `array` environment with the specialized `dcases` environment, which was designed for cases (pun intended) such as yours.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' env.
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}
f_X(x; \lambda, k) = 
\begin{dcases}
\frac{k}{\lambda}\Bigl(\frac{x}{k}\Bigr)^{k-1} \exp\bigl(-(x/\lambda)^k\bigr) & x \geq 0 \\[1ex]
0 & x < 0 
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Upvote your answer. But I'm curious to understand the difference between `cases` and `dcases`.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks! The main difference between the two environments is that `dcases` typesets its contents in `\displaystyle` math mode.